# Express doesn't send cookie to browser? (It sends postman)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies

I created a rest api with expess. When I was developing it, I used Postman to check request and response easily.
Now I started to learn ReactJs. I created a basic frontend that tries to login. But when I login with Reactjs app, I can't see the authorization token on chrome cookies. When I try to log in with Postman, everything works and I can see authorization token on Postman cookies. Should I do different things to send cookie to browsers?

[cookie sender function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJQHH.png)
here my  helper function that sends cookie to client.

[Postmant result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq8yB.png) and here the cookie result from Postman.

[Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHCAz.png) here my browser result

[Server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Tuf.png) and last my server file from express (should I use different middlewares?)

Thanks for help.

Comment: First of all: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1427878)

Comment: Besides what was already said about not posting code as an image. You don't show where/how `sendJwtToClient` is used. And not a comparison of how you do the request that generates that `access_token`  in Postman and how you do it in the browser. Because it works in Postman, indicates that you do the request in the browsers in a way, that does not match how you do the request in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your probably have our frontend running on a separate server than your backend. For example, a frontend on port 8080 and backend on 3000.

In React, you need to set up a proxy by adding the following to your package.json:

"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/